# "Include in Project" option missing from folder context menu in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm running VS2010 Pro SP1 (10.0.40219.1).  I copied/pasted a folder into my solution's directory in Windows Explorer, clicked the ghost button in VS' Solution Explorer so I can now see the folder from VS, right clicked on the folder, and the "Include in Project" context menu item is missing.

I can manually include all of the files within the directory tree, but that's a task considering this function once existed within my installation of Visual Studio.

This solution is an MVC3 Web App, but it appears to be happening with all solutions, Console Apps, etc.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu selection should be on the top-level Project menu.

If you don't have too many customizations, you could also try resetting all settings from the Tools -> Import and Export Settings... dialog.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Really should have been able to think of this on my own.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This works from within a project, but not from the solution level. You can add folders at the solution level, but solution level folders don't map to filesystem folders.

It would work if you had a project in the same folder. But you would be "including" the folder in the project, not the solution.

To add files from that folder, use Add > Existing Item. But the files you add this way will go to your `Solution Items` folder, which probably isn't what you wanted to do. The `Solution Items` folder simply maps to the actual solution folder.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified.  All of the folders I copied in are within the Content folder of my MVC Web Project within the Solution directory.